# Relationship Advice

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, geography

I have big news! I finally have a girlfriend! She's really nice and is studying to be a cartographer. As you know, I don't have much experience with the ladies, so I need some advice.

I have been sensing that things are not going well, and when I asked her what was wrong, she emailed me the attached map. She said that if I couldn't figure out what it meant, then I should probably ask you.

Any Ideas?

Your loving son,

Chowzen

[image: Map]
<sub>Click To Enlarge</sub>

> A correct answer will specifically identify the four points `A` `B` `C` `D` on the map as they pertain to the above letter.

<sub>As a bonus, you could suggest what a carefully worded response from Dear Old Dad would look like. :)</sub>

Comment: The premise for this made me think of [this gem](https://imgur.com/gallery/CoPw8) (warning: non-PG language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The route is indeed in Pennsylvania.
>  A: VIRGINVILLE
>  B: BLUE BALL
>  C: INTERCOURSE
>  D: CLIMAX
>  It would appear you're having trouble satisfying her in bed, due to your lack of sexual experience. A response might be Lickdale? Woodcock? There's a surprising amount of choice for Dear Old Dad here.

Answer (score 4):

I can't finish it, but:

> This is a route in Pennsylvania
>  (I recognized the Appalachian folds and the interstates between Altoona and Harrisburg)
>  I think:
>  D=Dayton (=Dating)
>  C=Lancaster (=???)
>  B=Ephrata (=afraid of)
>  A=Kutztown (=cuts town ??)

Comment: Other relevant locations that could correspond to the markers are, in ABCD order, rot13(ivetvaivyyr, oyhr onyy, vagrepbhefr, evattbyq).

Comment: @hdsdv - I didn't know there were so many funny names there, but those look a bit too far East to me (but I don't have map overlay) -- there's already a bad joke about going from rot13(vagrepbhefr gb pyvznk); would Chowzen go there?

Comment: Yeah - I was doing my best to line up "landmarks" but I'm not confident about any of them. I kind of zoomed in on the area that looked most correct and then looked for relevant names in the region. I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: I looked at the map and I thought the markers were: rot13(ivetvaivyyr, oyhr onyy, vagrepbhefr, naq pyvznk)

Comment: "Can't finish?" my condolences. :)